# Chat in Spring JSF e Primefaces

Tags: java-ee, spring, jsf-2.2, bootstrap, chat

Estou precisando desenvolver um chat para o nosso site.
Desenvolvido em:

- JSF 2.2
- Srping 4.2
- Hibernate 5
- Primefaces 5.3
- Css bootstrap

Já baixei um projeto do github, ele funciona legal, mas é muito pobre, queria um com banco de dados, css interessante.

Já vários post aqui, no stack em inglês e pela web, em php achei uns layouts bem show, mas usam bibliotecas de terceiros e muito javascrip.

Alguém tem dicas que podem me nortear a atender essas expectativas para o projeto.

O existe:

Esse é o projeto que baixei:
https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-chat

Dados do projeto:

- JavaScript library v2.0.0 http://knockoutjs.com/
- jquery-1.7.2.min.js
- chat.js

Funciona multiusuário bem legal, contras essas duas lib .js knockoutjs e esse chat.

Como esta o projeto esta online onde tem o site e um sistema rondado, já com as configurações acima de **desenvolvimento**.

Comment: Você já tem o websocket funcionando?

Comment: O que tenho funcionado comentei na pergunta, em si parece que tenho a coisa que preciso, mas não conheço **knockoutjs** e analisar esse chat.js, também não tem a ideia para e-mail, queria algo visual parecido com TAWK.TO, mas para java e jsf

Comment: Cara creio que você não vai encontrar nada pronto do jeito que você quer pra JSF. Vai ter que fazer na mão e ainda vai ficar um pouco limitado. É bem chato trabalhar com CSS no JSF

Comment: Quanto a css tranquilo, já to me viro bem nessa parte, uso o bootstrap css, isso ajuda muito ainda da uns perrengue, mas de boa, mas a estruturas de dados, (mensagem, usuário, convidados, comunicação, essa atualização síncrona, propagação da mensagem quando para convidado) entende nessa linha..